# Hide and Show Grid in ListView on Image inside Listview in Tapped Event Function

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

On the click of image inside a List view ,I want Like to hide a Grid which is in ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate. I have made Bindings also- IsVisible="{Binding ShowGrid}" on that Grid. I have taken Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274297/10223206 this post .But Struck , Visibility is not Changing . I am Sharing my Code for better understanding 
View Model-

```
  private bool _ShowGrid = false;
    public bool ShowGrid
    {
        get => _ShowGrid;
        set
        {
            _ShowGrid = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

In cs:_(Image Tap-Image Name - downarrow.png)

```
    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 

            Image image = sender as Image;
            string source = image.Source as FileImageSource;  //Getting the name of source as string
            if (String.Equals(source, "downarrow.png"))
            {
                image.Source = "uparrow.png";
                viewModel.ShowGrid = false;
            }
            else
            {
                image.Source = "downarrow.png";
                viewModel.ShowGrid = true;

            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var m = ex.Message;
        }


    }
```

Xaml-

```
  <ListView x:Name="MyListView"   IsGroupingEnabled="true" Footer=" "
                  HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="MyListView_ItemSelected" 
                  SeparatorColor="Transparent" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>

                            <Grid IsVisible="{Binding ShowGrid}" >


                                <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFit"  HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="30" 
                                                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                                       Source="checked.png" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SatusName}" FontSize="10"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Date}" FontSize="10"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>

                            <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="50"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                       Text="{Binding personName}" TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlue}" 
                                       FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"/>


                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  
                                       Text="{Binding Amount}"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                       TextColor="{StaticResource PrimaryBlue}" 
                                       FontSize="Medium" />

                                <Image Source="downarrow.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="ArrowImage"
                                       HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="30"
                                       HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1"/>
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
```

But Nothing Seems Work , it not hiding Grid on IMAGE CLICK. Kindly help me find a Solution.

.cs

```
 grouped = new ObservableCollection<GroupedOrderModel>();
            var person1Group = new GroupedOrderModel() { personName = "Personal loan" ,Amount="100"};
            var person2Group = new GroupedOrderModel() { personName = "Car Loan",Amount="300" };
            var person3Group = new GroupedOrderModel() { personName = "Rent Loan",Amount="400" };


            person1Group.Add(new StaffLoanStatus() { SatusName = "Approved", Date = "23-01-2019" });
            person1Group.Add(new StaffLoanStatus() { SatusName = "Pending", Date = "20-01-2019" });
            person1Group.Add(new StaffLoanStatus() { SatusName = "Declined", Date = "19-01-2019" });


            person2Group.Add(new StaffLoanStatus() { SatusName = "Approved", Date = "23-01-2019" });
            person2Group.Add(new StaffLoanStatus() { SatusName = "Pending", Date = "20-01-2019" });


            grouped.Add(person1Group);
            grouped.Add(person2Group);

            //Person3 without OrderModel
            grouped.Add(person3Group);

            MyListView.ItemsSource = grouped;
```

[image]

Comment: What is your ListView ItemsSource? in this cases, my solution is adding a bool property on your object, for example, public bool IsExpanded, and then, in code behind, you access the record like: var view = sender as View;
var theSelectedRecord = view?.BindingContext as YourObject;
and change the IsExpanded property and update de Source, i'm only commenting because i don't know for sure if this is what you are looking for.
One more question, are you using MVVM? or just plain code behind?

Comment: MVVM it is . Item Source is in cs. For testing only . I did something Like  MyListView.ItemsSource = grouped;

Comment: Just updated my answer with Item Source @RicardoDiasMorais . Have a look

Comment: @NancyKanwar Are you sure that "viewModel" you've used in the tap gesture callback and the bindingcontext of the page are the same instance ?

Comment: I am using a tapped function which is in cs file not view model .

Comment: okey, i'm gonna write a solution, it might help

Comment: Added an answer take a look

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais Okay

Comment: @G.hakim Okay ! Thankyou, Testing it

Comment: well, try @G.hakim solution first, it seems good, if it doesn't work, i will post how i do it

Comment: @NancyKanwar It doesn't matter what file you're using to have your tap gesture or whatever callback but you should understand what is going on the code. Hakim solution might not work if you're not using the bindingcontext instance attached with the page in the tap gesture callback.

Comment: You can't have multiple bindingcontext instances for a page and your code has incomplete information over which instance is being getting updated. An object x binded with the page has x.showgrid = false; and you didn't explain where you are updating it for initial load to make it x.showgrid= true. Which clearly states your binding wasn't working since you are able to see the expanded UI. Whatever hakim suggested is the key to the answer, but this forum is to learn not to find answers.

Comment: @Dilmah I am Sorry, I misunderstood your question , was struggling from long with this thing But i have binded it with same instance as:- StaffLoanPageViewModel viewModel=App.Locator.StaffLoanPageViewModel; (the x you mentioned ) .

Comment: @NancyKanwar glad you found your answer,  but i'm afraid you'll have to change your implementation of showgrid as ricardo suggested. Tbh ShowGrid should be a part of GroupOrderedModel rather than in the StaffLoanPageViewmodel.

Comment: This implementation is going to hide all your grids and the accordion expand/collapse which you're obviously trying to achieve is going to be a mess.

Comment: Can you explain more @Dilmah . yes this is hiding all Grids.

Comment: how can i explain this visualy.. after the ListView generated all the cells, all of them will have their visibility binded to your ShowGrid, so if you put it to false, all the grids will have their visibility change

Comment: Add a bool property to your GroupedOrderModel, and then Bind it like:
<Grid IsVisible="{Binding YourBoolPropertyFromModel}">, like you did for statusname for example

Comment: follow my first comment that explains how you can access that property of the clicked record and change it

Comment: @NancyKanwar Sorry it's pretty much hard to explain the solution for your prob, but the following link - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-expandable-listview-with-a-sub-listview-mvvm-pattern/ might help you understand how to handle the nested collections. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Dilmah Thankyou . This would help

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not working is the `BindingContext` since `ListViews` ItemsSource is it binding context anything outside it is alien to that DataTemplate try doing this:

```
IsVisible="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ShowGrid, Source={x:Reference MyListView}}"
```

Comment: Hey , I tried this , a slight issue is there. Space which  grid had is still there, Should it not vanish  when is  in visible , moreover When Clicked on Image of any List Item , it makes Grid in all List Items vanish . Can you suggest something related to it .